# Memory leak in PKCS12_newpass

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, openssl

I wrote function which changes PKCS12 certificate passphrase.

I noticed that PKCS12_newpass function leaks memory. When commenting out this line then memory leak is not generated.

How I could fix this memory leak?

```
- (NSData*)changePKCS12:(NSData*)p12Data
          oldPassphrase:(NSString*)oldPassphrase
          newPassphrase:(NSString*)newPassphrase {
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    BIO *bp = NULL;
    PKCS12 *p12 = NULL;
    int status = 0;
    do {
        bp = BIO_new_mem_buf((void *)[p12Data bytes], (int)[p12Data length]);    
        p12 = d2i_PKCS12_bio(bp, NULL);

        // MEMORY LEAK in PKCS12_newpass
        status = PKCS12_newpass(p12, (char *)[oldPassphrase UTF8String], (char *)[newPassphrase UTF8String]);
    } while (false);

    if (p12) {
        PKCS12_free(p12);
        p12 = NULL;
    }
    if (bp) {
        BIO_free_all(bp);
        bp = NULL;
    }
    EVP_cleanup();
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: A bug report was submitted for documentation at [Issue 4478: DOCUMENTATION PKCS12_newpass](https://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=4478&user=guest&pass=guest). It should help get beyond the "documentation else its private" rule. It also details the known memory leaks (due to this question, and it references the issues you filed).

Comment: The documentation was added to Master: [`PKCS12_newpass` man page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/PKCS12_newpass.html). Master means it will be available in 1.1.0; but It looks like its missing from 1.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the two leaks reported by Valgrind:

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full ./test.exe 
==32547== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==32547== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==32547== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==32547== Command: ./test.exe
==32547== 
==32547== 
==32547== HEAP SUMMARY:
==32547==     in use at exit: 4,044 bytes in 25 blocks
==32547==   total heap usage: 3,273 allocs, 3,248 frees, 149,992 bytes allocated
==32547== 
==32547== 1,307 (32 direct, 1,275 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 22 of 24
==32547==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32547==    by 0x408A76: CRYPTO_malloc (mem.c:140)
==32547==    by 0x408AA9: CRYPTO_zalloc (mem.c:148)
==32547==    by 0x447104: asn1_item_embed_new (tasn_new.c:171)
==32547==    by 0x446E66: ASN1_item_ex_new (tasn_new.c:88)
==32547==    by 0x4439AA: asn1_item_embed_d2i (tasn_dec.c:333)
==32547==    by 0x4431B7: ASN1_item_ex_d2i (tasn_dec.c:162)
==32547==    by 0x44314A: ASN1_item_d2i (tasn_dec.c:152)
==32547==    by 0x4AB8BA: PKCS12_item_decrypt_d2i (p12_decr.c:159)
==32547==    by 0x40CA79: PKCS8_decrypt (p12_p8d.c:69)
==32547==    by 0x40C8DC: newpass_bag (p12_npas.c:206)
==32547==    by 0x40C868: newpass_bags (p12_npas.c:188)
==32547== 
==32547== 2,625 (32 direct, 2,593 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 24 of 24
==32547==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32547==    by 0x408A76: CRYPTO_malloc (mem.c:140)
==32547==    by 0x408AA9: CRYPTO_zalloc (mem.c:148)
==32547==    by 0x41258E: sk_new (stack.c:153)
==32547==    by 0x41256A: sk_new_null (stack.c:146)
==32547==    by 0x40C27E: sk_PKCS7_new_null (pkcs7.h:199)
==32547==    by 0x40C489: newpass_p12 (p12_npas.c:118)
==32547==    by 0x40C3CC: PKCS12_newpass (p12_npas.c:96)
==32547==    by 0x40315F: main (in /home/openssl/test.exe)
```

The first one is due to `0x40C8DC: newpass_bag (p12_npas.c:206)`:

```
X509_SIG_get0(&shalg, NULL, bag->value.shkeybag);
```

However, the `get0` in `X509_SIG_get0` does not bump the reference count, so I think its really the line before it (or a bug in `X509_SIG_get0`):

```
if (PKCS12_SAFEBAG_get_nid(bag) != NID_pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag)
```

`PKCS12_SAFEBAG_get_nid` is not documented. That means its a private API, so the OpenSSL devs have to fix the leak caused by it. (I think its actually due to `PKCS12_item_decrypt_d2i` a little deeper into the stack, but its out of reach because of `PKCS12_SAFEBAG_get_nid`).

The second one is due to `0x40C489: newpass_p12 (p12_npas.c:118)`:

```
if ((newsafes = sk_PKCS7_new_null()) == NULL)
    return 0;
```

`sk_PKCS7_new_null` is not documented. That means its a private API, so the OpenSSL devs have to fix the leak caused by it.

---

> How I could fix this memory leak?

Unfortunately, you cannot because both of the offenders are private APIs. The best you can do it report them at [RT](http://www.openssl.org/community/#bugs), which is the [OpenSSL bug tracker](http://www.openssl.org/community/#bugs).

There was a somewhat unexpected "big deal" about documentation and private APIs and such. See [EC_KEY_priv2buf(): check parameter sanity](http://groups.google.com/d/msg/mailing.openssl.dev/RBmVd1nHXGE/5dA9lpVABQAJ) for a discussion and the new rules.

---

According to a search of the sources, `PKCS12_newpass` lacks documentation, so its a private API, too (there's no POD file, which is used to build the man page):

```
$ grep -IR PKCS12_newpass *
CHANGES:  *) New function PKCS12_newpass() which changes the password of a
crypto/pkcs12/pk12err.c:    {ERR_FUNC(PKCS12_F_PKCS12_NEWPASS), "PKCS12_newpass"},
crypto/pkcs12/p12_npas.c:int PKCS12_newpass(PKCS12 *p12, const char *oldpass, const char *newpass)
crypto.map:        PKCS12_newpass;
include/openssl/pkcs12.h:int PKCS12_newpass(PKCS12 *p12, const char *oldpass, const char *newpass);
util/libcrypto.num:PKCS12_newpass                          3204 1_1_0   EXIST::FUNCTION:
```

A bug report was submitted with documentation at [Issue 4478: DOCUMENTATION PKCS12_newpass](https://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=4478&user=guest&pass=guest). It should help get beyond the "documentation else its private" rule.

---

Below is a `cat test.cc`:

```c
#include "openssl/pkcs12.h"
#include "openssl/bio.h"
#include "openssl/engine.h"
#include "openssl/conf.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"

/* openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout key.pem -nodes -out cert.pem -days 365 */
/* openssl pkcs12 -export -out pkcs12.p12 -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem         */

/* gcc -ansi -I . -I ./include test.cc ./libcrypto.a -o test.exe */

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

  BIO *bp = NULL;
  PKCS12 *p12 = NULL;
  int rc = -1;
  unsigned long err = 0;
  char password[] = "passphrase";

  bp =  BIO_new_file("pkcs12.p12", "r");
  if (bp == NULL) goto cleanup;

  p12 = d2i_PKCS12_bio(bp, NULL);
  if (p12 == NULL) goto cleanup;

  /* Use empty string when no password was applies with 'openssl pkcs12' */
  rc = PKCS12_newpass(p12, password, password);

cleanup:

  if (rc == 1)
    {
      fprintf(stdout, "Sucessfully changed password\n");
    }
  else
    {
      err = ERR_get_error();
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to change password, error %lu\n", err);
    }

  if (p12)
    PKCS12_free(p12);

  if (bp)
    BIO_free_all(bp);

  /* http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization#Cleanup */
  ENGINE_cleanup();
  CONF_modules_unload(1);
  EVP_cleanup();
  CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data();
#if OPENSSL_API_COMPAT < 0x10000000L
  ERR_remove_state(0);
#else
  ERR_remove_thread_state();
#endif
  ERR_free_strings(); 

  return 0;
}
```